# Count multiple columns if they contain specific text using the counta function

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am working on a project for my sociology class. We have collected data in a Google spreadsheet using Google Forms. Specifically, I am trying to formulate a function that will count the number of times both columns I and F contain the text "Night (7:00-3:00)" and "Dark". It doesn't matter to me if the word "Dark" in column I is part of a list of other words, as long as it appears, I want it to be counted. So far, I have come up with these two functions:

```
=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SEARCH("Dark",I2:I))))
```

= 38

```
=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SEARCH("Night (7:00-3:00)",F2:F))))
```

= 35

They work successfully separately, but I have no idea how to combine them so that I get a result that is a combination of both criteria being true.

My problem is that when I use a function that counts both strings of text, it excludes all of the times "Dark" appears in a cell when it is accompanied by other words. For example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(countif(F2:F114&I2:I114,"Night (7:00-3:00)"&"Dark*"))
```

= 2

I am not very well versed in Google Sheets. Thank you for your help.
Here is a link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D7I4pn5Ajuph432WDn1idCPSeU8GbA2BTMW8OQit4mU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Use countifs:
`=countifs(I2:I99,"*"&"Dark"&"*",F2:F99,"*"&"Night (7:00-3:00)"&"*"))`

Change I2:I99 and F2:F99 to correspond to your Data
Countifs works with multiple criteria at the same time

Comment: Could just be `..., "*Dark*", ...`

Comment: Thank you so much yass! This worked perfectly. And thank you Jeeped as well. (I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to upvote this.)

Comment: How can I mark TRUE for a range of cells in a row (U5:X5) if 3 or more of those cells contain the word TRUE?